# Meaning of $ within LTspice netlist

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to further understand the .cir file I have downloaded from Infineon that I am using to model some of their mosfets in LTspice.

In the below example can anyone explain the lines starting with X$M? I can't find this format in any notes elsewhere

[image]

(note: Z27 and Z28 are other .subckt functions in the same .cir file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that it's just an atypical character that's used simply because it's allowed and it stands out. The line starts with `X`, which is the designator for subcircuit. Whatever characters follow afterwards have to meet one single criterium: they have to be allowed by the parser (i.e. no errors should appear, the circuit should run).

`$` and the `M` afterwards might suggest that it's an artifice simiar to what LTspice does when it substitutes elements, behind the scene. For example using `[Misc]/Epoly` with the `FREQ` keyword (bogus example):

`E1 out 0 FREQ {V(in)} (0,0,0) (1,1,1) (2,3,4)`

makes the expanded netlist to show up this line:

`B§E1 out 0 V=V(in) FREQ (0,0,0) (1,1,1) (2,3,4)`

So in this case it might be that some MOSFET (which `M` designates) might be involved, as in there was a schematic which had a subcircuit mimicking an MOSFET (it had the designator `M`), but LTspice detected it's not a `.model` and, when the general subcircuit was created, someone replaced the `§` with the `$`. The not labels seem to agree. It could be, it could be not. But the end result is that it's an allowed character and can be safely used; nothing to worry about.